# How can I choose which live video to play from red5 server using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, webcam, red5

If there are several users who are streaming videos from their webcams to a red5 server, how can I choose which stream to play using AS3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a list of the stream ids published and then play it using a NetStream object.

```
var nc:NetStream = new NetStream(netConnection)
video.attachNetStream(nc);
nc.play("streamId");
```

Comment: How can I create this list?

Comment: well when the user publish the webcam, invoke a function in the server to store the the streamId in a list... this list can be a static list in the server side class